# For what rational d is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be a field of rational numbers and d $\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Consider the set $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}] := \{a + b\sqrt{d} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ and define operations:

\begin{gathered}
(a + b\sqrt{d}) + (a' + b'\sqrt{d}) := (a + a') + (b + b')\sqrt{d}\\
(a + b\sqrt{d}) * (a' + b'\sqrt{d}) := (aa' + dbb') + (ab' + a'b)\sqrt{d}
\end{gathered}

It's easy to check that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ is a commutative ring with identity $1 := 1 + 0\sqrt{d}$.

For some $d$ we can define an operation of taking inverse of non-zero elements. For what d does this hold?

Comment: The two laws are identical???

Comment: You seem to have mistyped the multiplication. Consider instead the question: When can you *not* take inverses?

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb Q[d]$ is a field for all $d\in\mathbb Q$. To find the inverse of an element $a+b\sqrt d$, you can use exactly the same trick you use to find the inverse of a complex number:

$$\frac 1 {a+b\sqrt d}=\frac {a-b\sqrt d}{(a-b\sqrt d)(a+b\sqrt d)}=\frac{a-b\sqrt d}{a^2-db^2}=\frac{a}{a^2-db^2}+\frac{-b}{a^2-db^2}\sqrt d$$

That is to say, since we know that the inverse definitely exists in $\mathbb C$, or even in $\mathbb R$ is $d$ is positive, the above reasoning shows that it is in fact in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ is a field for all $d \in \mathbb{Q}$ where $d \neq a^2/b^2$ ?

Comment: If $d=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$ then $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]=\mathbb{Q}$ which is also a field

Answer (score 1):

If you ***define*** $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ as the ***set of symbols $a + b\sqrt{d}$, two such symbols $a + b\sqrt{d}, a' + b'\sqrt{d}$ being equal iff $a = a'$, $b = b'$***, with the given operations (alternatively, you have the set of pairs $(a, b)$, with the given operations), then the answer is: this is a field iff $d$ is not a perfect square in $\mathbb{Q}$.

In fact if $d = u^{2}$ for some $u \in \mathbb{Q}$, you have
$$
(u - \sqrt{d}) (u + \sqrt{d}) = u^{2} - d = 0, 
$$
so $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ is not even a domain.

If $d$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}$, then the argument in another answer shows that you get a field.

Comment: Are you sure? If d is a perfect square, the $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]=\mathbb{Q}$ which is a field

Comment: @EdouardL., as I tried to stress in my answer (***it's in italic bold***), it is a matter of definitions. If $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ stands for the smallest subring of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{d}$, of course you are right. But OP appeared to write elements as symbols. In other words, if we are talking the set of pairs with sum $(a, b) + (a', b') = (a + a', b + b')$ and product $(a, b) \cdot (a', b') = (a a' + d b b', ab' + ba')$, then my argument stands.

Comment: Yes, I mean formal expressions of this type

Comment: @Zudwa, thanks for the clarification. Alas, somebody thought me wrong with this, and downvoted my answer - but I can live with it.

Comment: @EdouardL., you see...

Comment: @AndreasCaranti  Sir, I did not get your answer. To show it has zero divisors, we need to show "product of two nonzero elements is zero". But isn't both $u-\sqrt{d}$ and $u+\sqrt{d}$ are already zero? Since $d=u^2$ so that, $u-\sqrt{d}=u-\sqrt{u^2}=u-u=0$. Further, answer by "Jack M " shows that $Q[√d]$ is field for all rationals $d$ (not only for square free rationals). please reply